# Move to Azure Resource Manager REST APIs for Azure SQL Database by December 1, 2019

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I got a message in my email, "Move to Azure Resource Manager REST APIs for Azure SQL Database by December 1, 2019".
I am not sure what I should do? how can I know the I am actually using "classic Azure Service Manager deployment model"? and how can I move to the new "Azure Resource Manager"?
noting that I have an Azure SQL database in production in my Azure portal.

thanks,
Mohammad

Comment: I dont think that's not possible. Azure SQL was "auto migrated" to ARM.

Comment: Refer link:- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/12/03/move-to-azure-resource-manager-rest-apis-for-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

This article explain perfectly what is exactly the migration and if you need to do something. [Move to Azure Resource Manager REST APIs for Azure SQL Database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/12/03/move-to-azure-resource-manager-rest-apis-for-azure-sql-database/)

In summary:

Only affect you if you have some call to the API endpoint for Azure Service Manager (ASM).